# logic apps to load the content of an excel and then convert it to a csv

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I need to load the content of an excel and then convert it to a csv using logic apps. What's the way to do it? I have tried excel (one drive) connector and it has an action of list rows present in a table, which can only list the rows of an excel table, but in my case the excel has just plain data with no table defined. Other actions in excel connector are like list all sheets, list all tables etc but none of these seem to get the content of the excel when there is no table. Can anyone suggest is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Did you mean your excel has no table so you couldn't list rows with list rows present in a table? So did you try Get a row action? If this action works, maybe you could use this action with an "Until" loop.

Comment: You could read excel content with azure functions and inject it into logic app. Please refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171845/download-an-excel-file-and-read-content-with-azure-functions).