# Convert Excel file to CSV using Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a blob storage which contains both csv and excel files. I need to convert excel files into csv files which I will process using Azure Data Factory and I wanted to know how to do this using PowerShell within Azure Function. If not PowerShell I don't mind any other language.

I receive excel files regularly.

I have never used Azure Functions before so this is a new area for me. I will be using VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

As Excel itself cannot be installed in the Function host, you need to do something like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43228473/1537195) similar answer. There the Open XML SDK is used to manipulate Excel files. The same library should provide you a way to simply read the content and write to a CSV file.